# Sorting items alphabetically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am re-posting this question because I made a mistake when I first posted it: I didn't try hard enough before asking. And I would like to apologize to the community for asking it to do my work for me

I am trying to alphabetically order unordered lists inside a div. Not the list item's inside of the unordered lists, but the unordered lists themselves.

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="FindByCategory">
    <ul>
         <li> B. This is the first list item in the second unordered list</li>
         <li> B. This is the second list item in the second unordered list</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
         <li> A. This is the first list item in the first unordered list</li>
         <li> A. This is the second list item in the first unordered list</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
<div class="FindByCategory">
    <ul>
         <li> A. This is the first list item in the first unordered list</li>
         <li> A. This is the second list item in the first unordered list</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
         <li> B. This is the first list item in the second unordered list</li>
         <li> B. This is the second list item in the second unordered list</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
    <script>
        function sortUnorderedList(div.FindByCategory, sortDescending) {
  if(typeof div.FindByCategory == "string")
    div = document.getElementById(div.FindByCategory);
  var uls = ul.getElementsByTagName("UL");
  var vals = [];
  for(var i = 0, l = uls.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(uls[i].innerHTML);
  vals.sort();
  for(var i = 0, l = uls.length; i < l; i++)
    uls[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}
$(function(){
    FindByCategory()
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When sorting any DOM nodes, there are three simple steps:

1. Build an array of the nodes to sort, accompanied by what part of them you are sorting (if it is not a readily accessible property).
2. Sort the array.
3. Rebuild the DOM tree based on the new order.

In this case, the nodes you want to sort are matched by `#FindByCategory > ul`, and you are effectively sorting by their text content. So:

```
var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("#FindByCateory > ul"), l = qsa.length, i, arr = [];
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    arr[i] = [qsa[i],qsa[i].textContent || qsa[i].innerText];
    // the text content is not readily accessible, since it depends on the browser
}
// now sort the array:
arr.sort(function(a,b) {return a[1] < b[1] ? -1 : (a[1] == b[1] ? 0 : 1);});
// and now re-append them
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    arr[i][0].parentNode.appendChild(arr[i][0]);
    // by re-appending the nodes, they will emerge sorted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                var array = new Array();

                for(var i = 0 ; i<4 ; i++){

                    var string = $("li:eq("+i+")").text();
                    array[i]  = string;

                }

                array.sort();

                alert(array);


            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a Swiss army knife sorting plugin for jQuery. http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/